# How to ignore blank xml files in Project while scanning with SonarQube

Tags: xml, sonarqube

I have a java project where there are many xml files.  Some of them are blank.  SonarQube gives error when it scan such files.

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
```

Is there a way i can instruct SonarQube to ignore them?

I am SonarQube 4.5.7.

Comment: Do you have the SonarXML analyzer installed?

Comment: yes I do have SonarXML.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude them:

```
sonar.exclusions=yourPath/*.xml
```

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus

Comment: there are many XMLs which are empty and in different places.  Isn't there any thing in a configuration level.

Comment: Why not `sonar.exclusions=**/*.xml`?